# How to undo all code from one frame in as3

Tags: actionscript-3

how can I undo or disable the code that I used in an previous frame?
I have been working with `Event.ENTER_FRAME` and I know that I can use `stage.removeEventListener` to undo the code but my code is a bit too difficulty and I'm not a great coder so maybe there is an simple code which disables all the code in the previous frame, is that possible? 
this is the code what I have:

```
stop();
import com.greensock.*; 
import com.greensock.easing.*;
import com.greensock.TweenMax;
import com.greensock.TweenLite;
import flash.events.Event;

var myTween:TweenLite;
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, rijden); // Add the button click

function rijden(e:MouseEvent):void {
    trace('start car timer');
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, rijden); // unplug "rijden" handler
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, spring); // Add the button click
    var randNum:Number;

    randNum = Math.round(Math.random() * 5 + 2000);
    trace(randNum);
    var timer:Timer = new Timer(randNum);
    timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, randGen);

    function randGen(e:TimerEvent):void {
        var timerObj:Timer = e.target as Timer;
        randNum = Math.round(Math.random() * 5 + 2000);
        myTween = TweenLite.to(auto, 4, {x:666.15, y:375.6});
        timerObj.delay = randNum;
        trace('shootCar');
        timer.stop();
    }
    timer.start();
}

var grav:Number = 7.5;
var jumping:Boolean = false;
var jumpPow:Number = 0;

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);

function spring(e:MouseEvent):void {
    trace('spring');
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, spring); // unplug "spring" handler
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, rijden);
    if(jumping != true){   
        TweenLite.to(man, 0.5, {rotation:360});
        jumpPow = -50;
        jumping = true;
    }  
}  

function update(evt:Event):void{
    if(jumping){
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);
        man.y += jumpPow;
        jumpPow += grav;
        if(man.y >= 375){
            jumping = false;
            man.y = 375;
        }
    }
}


var autoWasHitByMan=false;
var manWasHitByEind=false;
var autoWasHitByStopauto=false;


addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, hit);
function hit(e:Event){
    if(auto.hitTestObject(man) && !autoWasHitByMan){
        trace("auto hits man");
        autoWasHitByMan=true;
        TweenLite.to(man, 4, {x:539.95, y:145, rotation:360});
this.setChildIndex(level, this.numChildren - 1);
        TweenMax.to(level, 1, {scaleX:1, scaleY:3, ease:Elastic.easeOut});
        this.setChildIndex(facebook, this.numChildren - 1);
var timer:Timer = new Timer(2000, 1); // delay = time between ticks in milliseconds
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, onTimerComplete);
timer.start();

function onTimerComplete(e:TimerEvent):void
{
    // remove listener
    timer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, onTimerComplete);
removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, hit);
    var myTween4:TweenMax = new TweenMax(level, 1, {scaleX:0, scaleY:0, ease:Linear.easeOut});// advance playhead to frame 2
    gotoAndStop(2);



facebook.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, shareClickHandler);

function shareClickHandler(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    var varsShare:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
    varsShare.u = 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ea.games.nfs13_row';
    varsShare.t = 'Try to beat me if you can';

    var urlFacebookShare:URLRequest = new URLRequest('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php');
    urlFacebookShare.data = varsShare;
    urlFacebookShare.method = URLRequestMethod.GET;

    navigateToURL(urlFacebookShare, '');
}

    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, shareClickHandler);

}
        }


    if(man.hitTestObject(eind) && !manWasHitByEind){
        trace("man hits eind");
        manWasHitByEind=true;
        man.x = 241.3;
        man.y = 375;
    }
    if(auto.hitTestObject(stopauto) && !autoWasHitByStopauto){
        trace("auto hits stopauto");
        autoWasHitByStopauto=true;
        myTween.kill();    
        auto.x = 241;
        auto.y = 375;
    }
    if(auto.hitTestObject(nextlevel) && autoWasHitByMan==false && lives > 1 ){
        trace("boeoboeobo")
        stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, spring);
        stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, rijden);
        stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);
        stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, hit);
    "this is the plce where the hit event has to be stoped I think because I get an error in the next level."
        gotoAndPlay(1, "Scène 2")
        }
}
```

Comment: No there is no simple way. What code do you have to disable?

Comment: You have a couple options here, but please edit in some of the code you don't want to have run on the next frame.

Comment: What code do you not want to have run? All of it? Is removing the listener not working currently when you do `stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, hit);`

Comment: @p1on I get this error if TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at ::MainTimeline/hit2()[::frame4:78]
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at::MainTimeline/hit()[...MainTimeline::frame1:78] so it refers to both hit events so I think that both events or at least one of them has to remove

Comment: So `man` display object is null? I copied your code into the timeline, and at line 78 in `hit()` `man.x` is being changed. Which would mean you would need to evaluate it at the very least before attempting to change the x value. That is `if ( man && man.hasOwnProperty("x") )`

Comment: @p1on no sorry that was not my whole code it has nothing to do with the x value of the man object at my code the error is on this line: if(auto.hitTestObject(man) && !autoWasHitByMan){   but I will add an code that might be important for you to discover my problem

Comment: Sounds like you just need the first part of the circuit `if ( man ) { //code }`

Comment: @p1on I don't get it what do you mean?

Comment: `if(auto.hitTestObject(man) && !autoWasHitByMan)` uses the display objects `auto` and `man`. You should make sure both of those are not null before referencing. So it would look like: 
`if ( auto && man ) {
    if(auto.hitTestObject(man) && !autoWasHitByMan) { //code }
}` This evaluates `auto` and `man` to make sure they are not null before referencing.

Comment: @p1on that doesn't work I have put "boeoboeobo" in a trace when auto.hitTestObject(nextlevel) and it traces it in frame one but in frame 2 I have put some other text to trace but it still traces "boeoboeobo" again so I think that the eventlistener hit isn't removed, since all the code is within the hit event

Comment: Yeah without proper debugging I'm just taking stabs in the dark. I think the real answer is don't do extensive coding in the timeline. Based on the null reference error and line you said it was on, the evaluation should have worked for avoiding using a null reference. But without seeing your FLA, you are describing issues that may or may not be related. The best way for me to help you with this is to post your FLA on dropbox or another file sharing service, otherwise this is too cryptic for me to solve.

Comment: @p1on yeah I understand, here is can you find my fla: https://www.dropbox.com/s/n8qlggygnnm7v0e/stackoverflowerror.fla

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44352/discussion-between-p1on-and-user2852398)

Answer (score 0):

```
switch(currentLabel)
{
    case frameLabelName:
        //your code here
    break;
    case frameLabelName2:
        //another code here
    break;
}
```

Do I recomend you to do it? NO! Create classes and don't program inside the frames to avoid *disable code*.